# Populating recyclerview - nothing happens

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have two recyclerviews, one to select a category, and one with various items belonging to various categories. When I click on a category in my first recyclerview, I would like to see only the items in that category displayed in the second recyclerview. In my displayDataItems method, the System.out.print gives me the correct filtered data. However, in my recyclerview, when I select a category, all items in all categories are still displayed.I'd be grateful for some pointers. Thanks in advance!

This is in my dataProvider class:

```
public static Predicate<DataItem> predAnimals = new Predicate<DataItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(DataItem dItem) {
        return (dItem.getCategory() == "Animals");
    }
};

public static void displayDataItems(List<DataItem> dataItemList, final Predicate<DataItem> pred) {
    for (DataItem dItem : dataItemList) {
        if (pred.apply(dItem)){
            System.out.println(dItem);
        }

    }
}
```

And this is in my category recyclerAdapter class:

```
        holder.myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String itemName = item.getItemName();
            Intent intent = new Intent (catContext, SelectionPage.class);
            intent.putExtra(ITEM_KEY_TWO, itemName);
            catContext.startActivity(intent);

            switch (itemName){
                case "Animals":
                    SampleDataProvider.displayDataItems(dataItemList, predAnimals);
                    Toast.makeText(catContext, "Animals", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case "Cartoons":
                    Toast.makeText(catContext, "Cartoons", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you need `dItem.getCategory().equals("Animals")`

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that I need to replace (dItem.getCategory() == "Animals") with dItem.getCategory().equals("Animals")? The problem remains...

Comment: yup , and you are just printing items of `list` , can't see any code where you are setting recyclerview , but as per logic , you neel to replace the list currently used by your recyclerview with the one containing all animals and after replacing use `notifydatasetchange`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the help! :)

Comment: i am glad that i could help , happy coding and typo in my previous comment , it's need not neel

Comment: Sorry, one more question: I am not managing to refresh my list using notifydatachanged. I used this in my recycler page's onCreate method:        final DataItemAdapter adapter = new DataItemAdapter(this, newDataItemList); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged;
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvItems);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged;` when you already have adapter created and shown but later you change the data and want to refresh the list